# How to replace a string with a variable in an angular *ngIf

Tags: angular

I have a div in my template which i want to hide base on a value of a certain form control and that's where I run into some issues. The below format works fine

```
<div *ngIf="form.value[question.key] ==='other'">
```

But the issue is how do i replace the 'other' with a value from my question object called
**childhidevalue** i tried [question.childhidevalue], ['question.childhidevalue'] and
{{question.childhidevalue}} with no luck.

Comment: Did you try just `question.childhidevalue`? It's a bit hard helping you with the information you've given, please include some code that shows what the question object looks like and how you've set up your form.

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div *ngIf="form.value[question.key] === question.childhidevalue">
```

Comment: Thanks, sometimes so simple is the answer